# Cannot create airbrake.jar file

Tags: android, jar, airbrake

I want to use [Air brake SDK](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-android) in my project

, but while creating the jar file I am getting the error.

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/standarduser/Downloads/airbrake-android-master/build.xml:30: /usr/local/android_sdk/platforms/android-7 does not exist.
```

In the build.xml, I tried updating the     
 to     
but again the same error. Please help.

Comment: you can also add direct class to your project no need to add jar

Comment: Ok, you mean should I directly add the java file in any of my packages in android studio and it will work ??

Comment: Thanks, now I can register for Airbrake.. Do you have any idea how to test it if it is working properly or not..?

Comment: you can check your crash report on that dashboard with your app key

Comment: Yes.. I'll surely check it through dashboard, but I am not getting any alert saying "Send error report" or so.. Is that works the same way ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75704/discussion-between-anand-makwana-and-bhavna).

Answer (score 2):

if you are looking to use [Airbrake Bug Tracker](https://airbrake.io/) then you can easily add in gradle file if you are using Android Studio

```
dependencies {
    compile 'io.airbrake:airbrake-java:2.2.8'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help sir,, but as Anand suggested, using the java file worked for me.

Comment: I knew it would be okay, just posted the answer in case people comes here  for similar problem, cheers :)